# SQL Server To MySQL conversion script error surrounding UUID()?

Tags: mysql, database

```
ALTER TABLE aspnet_Paths ALTER PathId SET DEFAULT UUID();
```

I've ran a converter program on "generate" scripts from a SQL Server database.
I seem to be having uuid in the above statement highlighted in work benches query window with the statement "Error Syntax near uuid()",

I'm moving to MySQL. What's the correct implementation of this statement?

Any help/advise is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
BEFORE INSERT
ON aspnet_paths
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.PathId IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.PathId = UUID();
  END IF;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: this is Abit mad i was on your site today and yesterday over how llblgen would communicate with mysql, anyways i have about 100 or more of the line mentioned above in a generate script from sql server, is there no simpler solution or is MySQL just that awkward about this ? migrating is such a headache

Comment: MySQL does not support functions in the DEFAULT clause; it is only possible to set current time for TIMESTAMP fields.